# How to comprehend a group of nested finite-dimensional subspaces? Can we prove that they are a subspace of V?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let's consider I have a family of nested subspaces where $U_1$ is a subset of $U_2$ which is a subset (or equal to) of $U_3$ and so on, up till some finite $j$ and all of these are subspaces of some vector space $V$.

To be specific, how could I go about proving that $U := \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty U_j$ is a subspace of $V$ too? Can I also say that the dimension of this $U$ would be greater than or equal to the dimension of $U_k$ for all $k$'s?

Would appreciate any hints regarding the direction I should take.

Answer (score 1):

Do you recall the definition of a linear subspace? It is a subset that is *closed under linear combinations of its elements*.

Now consider that for any two elements of your union $x,y\in U$ they are both in some $U_i,U_j$ respectively by definition of the union. Since the subspaces are *nested*, one of these two subspaces is contained in the other and so $x,y$ are both members of $U_i$, say.

Can you see how to complete the proof now?

Edit: With regards to your second question, recall that any basis of a $U_k$ is a linearly independent subset of the union $U$ and any linearly independent subset of a vector space can be extended to form a basis. Thus the dimension of $U$ is greater than or equal to the dimension of $U_k$.